# Unable to succesfully add system call in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c, system-calls

I am following [this article](http://sreeramz.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/hello-world-system-call-2/) to add a system call. followed all the steps without any issue. And yes one step is missing there, that of **make menuconfig**

However when I am running the following code, I am getting error:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define __NR_hello_world 312

long hello_world_syscall(void) {
    return syscall(__NR_hello_world);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])

 {

    long int a = hello_world_syscall();

    printf("System call returned %ld\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
System call returned -1
```

I noticed that in arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h

```
#define __NR_process_vm_readv   347
#define __NR_process_vm_writev  348
#define __NR_hello_world        349  /*added by me, but I see 349 is also given below*/

#ifdef __KERNEL__

#define NR_syscalls 349

#define __ARCH_WANT_IPC_PARSE_VERSION
#define __ARCH_WANT_OLD_READDIR
#define __ARCH_WANT_OLD_STAT
#define __ARCH_WANT_STAT64
```

Is it wrong?

Also in arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h

```
__SYSCALL(__NR_process_vm_readv, sys_process_vm_readv)
#define __NR_process_vm_writev                  311
__SYSCALL(__NR_process_vm_writev, sys_process_vm_writev)

/*added by me*/
#define __NR_hello_world                        312     
__SYSCALL(__NR_hello_world, sys_hello_world)    

#ifndef __NO_STUBS
#define __ARCH_WANT_OLD_READDIR
#define __ARCH_WANT_OLD_STAT
#define __ARCH_WANT_SYS_ALARM
#define __ARCH_WANT_SYS_GETHOSTNAME
#define __ARCH_WANT_SYS_PAUSE
#define __ARCH_WANT_SYS_SGETMASK
#define __ARCH_WANT_SYS_SIGNAL
```

Also I edited the file: include/linux/syscalls.h  at the end before endif

```
                                  unsigned long liovcnt,
                                     const struct iovec __user *rvec,
                                     unsigned long riovcnt,
                                     unsigned long flags);
asmlinkage long sys_process_vm_writev(pid_t pid,
                                      const struct iovec __user *lvec,
                                      unsigned long liovcnt,
                                      const struct iovec __user *rvec,
                                      unsigned long riovcnt,
                                      unsigned long flags);




asmlinkage long sys_hello_world(void); /*added by me*/

#endif
```

The above two files are in the source code that I downloaded, and then compiled, and installed.

I also did dmesg, but nowhere I see my system call being called.

Any idea what is wrong here?

OS. is Ubuntu 12.04, kernel is:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I know nothing about system calls, but logical places to look are `errno` and see what that says, and upping `NR_syscalls` to 350 and try again.

Comment: System calls are implemented in the kernel.  You're asking about invoking a custom one from userspace, but are you running a kernel that actually implements this new system call number?  It looks like you're just running the stock Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Also, why are you defining `__NR_hello_world` as 312 in some places and 349 in others?

Comment: @Wyzard You are right. I don't know how do I boot the latest kernel. In my bootloader, I see only windows7 and ubuntu. my boot-loader is grub

Comment: It's not a matter of getting a "latest" kernel.  If you want to add a new system call, you have to actually implement that system call in the kernel yourself.  That means editing the kernel source code and compiling a new, custom kernel on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add line

## define  __NR_hello_world        350

in 
arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h

Add entry in kernel table
 #sudo gedit arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl

write follwing at the end of 64 bit table entries.

350    common    hello    sys_hello